# Using JSN with Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to send JSON request using Python, but I receive an error when I try to create JSON object using the following format:

```
data="{
"auth": {
  "tenantName": "user1",
  "passwordCredentials": {
  "username": "user1",
  "password": "pass"
  }
 }
}"
```

The error message is:

> ```
> File "auth.py", line 5
>     data="{
>           ^
> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply create a dict and use `json.dumps()` to create a JSON string from it.

```
import json

data = json.dumps({
    'auth': {
        'tenantName': 'user1',
        'passwordCredentials': {
            'username': 'user1',
            'password': 'pass'
        }
    }
})
```

What you did is invalid since you can't have linebreaks in a "normal" quoted string - you'd have to use triple quotes instead. However, don't do that. Creating JSON using string functions is a bad idea, even if it's just dumpling a hand-crafted JSON string into a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your string definition is invalid, you cannot use multiple lines and `"` quotes in a string delimited by just a single `"` quote. The following works:

```
data="""{
"auth": {
  "tenantName": "user1",
  "passwordCredentials": {
  "username": "user1",
  "password": "pass"
  }
 }
}"""
```

as that uses triple-quoting.

You may want to consider using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) instead to produce valid JSON, this reduces the chances for errors greatly:

```
import json

data = {
    'auth': {
        'tenantName': 'user1',
        'passwordCredentials': {
            'username': 'user1',
            'password': 'pass'
        }
    }
}

data = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: I wouldn't even suggest him to write the JSON string manually inside a string... He might end up doing that instead of using `json.dumps` ;)